# running jquery ui-effect "hightlight" at the same time as localScroll

Tags: jquery, scroll

im using the jquery ui effect 'higlight' with ariel fleslers' local scroll. and i want both functions to run at the same time. the problem is, as for now, the functions are making each other queue.
thats what my document.ready function looks like:

$(".button").click(function () {
      $('body').effect("highlight", {color:"#b0b8ff"}, 1000);

$('.navi').localScroll({
    duration: 2000,
    lazy: true,
    hash: true
});

written like that, the localScroll plugin waits until the highlight effect is done. setting "lazy" to false, the highlight effect is only executed after local scroll is done?!

am i missing something? is there a way to accomplish what i wanted?
thank you in advance,

denis

Answer (score 3):

By default, jQuery UI effects will add a queue for each animation, but you can manually call  the function .dequeue() to automatically start the next effect in queue, like this:

```
$('#my_div').effect("highlight", {}, 1000).dequeue().effect('shake', { distance:5 }, 50)
```

This will shake and highlight the div at the same time.